# Standard format for quantity in derived dimension in `pint`

Tags: python, pint

**TLDR:** I'd like to have `pint` quantities, that are in a certain (derived) dimension, to be converted into a pre-set unit by default.

---

**Details:**

I deal with 5 dimensions, as specified below. Note that [power] (usually in MW) and [price] (usually in Eur/MWh) are the derived dimensions.

```
# units.txt

# Base dimensions and their units
hour = [time] = h = hr
megawatthour = [energy] = MWh
euro = [currency] = Eur = €

# Derived dimensions and their units
[power] = [energy] / [time]
megawatt = megawatthour / hour = MW
[price] = [currency] / [energy]
euro_per_MWh = euro / megawatthour  = Eur/MWh
```

My question: is it possible to specify that *calculated* quantities with dimension [power] are by default to be converted to MW?

---

Here's an example:

```py
import pint

ureg = pint.UnitRegistry("units.txt",)
ureg.default_format = ".0f~P"

energy = 100 * ureg.MWh
time = 4 * ureg.h
revenue = 4000 * ureg.euro

price = revenue / energy
power = energy / time

print(energy, time, revenue, price, power) 
# 100 MWh 4 h 4000 Eur 40 Eur/MWh 25 MWh/h
```

Here, the power is expressed in *MWh/h*, because of the way it is calculated, and I can 'convert' it to *MW* by calling `power.to('MW')`. **Is it possible to automatically do this every time a quantity in this dimension is calculated?**

Note that doing a blanket `.to_base_units()` on all quantities reverts it back to *MWh/h*.

Remarks:

- I don't want to use [power] as a base dimension. It moves the problem to the price anyway.
- I'm aware of prefixes; I just left them out here to keep the example as short as possible.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge Pint doesn't currently support setting desired conversion preferences. There has been some chatter about this on the project repo and this [issue](https://github.com/hgrecco/pint/issues/242) links to a string of related issues.

What you want can be achieved with some custom code with the caveat that the output needs to be wrapped in a function.

```
# units-2.txt

# Base dimensions and their units
hour = [time] = h = hr
megawatt = [power] = MW 
euro = [currency] = Eur = €

# Derived dimensions and their units
[energy] = [power] * [time]
megawatthour = megawatt * hour = MWh
[price] = [currency] / [energy]
euro_per_MWh = euro / megawatthour  = Eur/MWh
```

```py
import pint

preference = ["Eur/MWh", 'MW']

def beautify(x, preference=preference):
    for preferred_unit in preference:
        try:
            return x.to(preferred_unit)
        except pint.DimensionalityError:
            pass
    # if no preferred unit fits, leave it as it is
    return x

def test_defs(file):
    print(file)
    ureg = pint.UnitRegistry(file,)
    ureg.default_format = ".0f~P"
    energy = 100 * ureg.MWh
    time = 4 * ureg.h
    revenue = 4000 * ureg.euro
    price = revenue / energy
    power = energy / time
    print(time.to_base_units())
    print(f"beautified time: {beautify(time)}")  # Units with no preference remain the same.
    print(power.to_base_units())
    print(f"beautified power: {beautify(power)}")  # Units with preference can be changed.
    print(price.to_base_units())
    print(f"beautified price: {beautify(price)}")  # Units with preference can be changed.

test_defs("units.txt")
test_defs("units-2.txt")
```

This will print

```
units.txt
4 h
beautified time: 4 h
25 MWh/h
beautified power: 25 MW
40 Eur/MWh
beautified price: 40 Eur/MWh
units-2.txt
4 h
beautified time: 4 h
25 MW
beautified power: 25 MW
40 Eur/MW/h
beautified price: 40 Eur/MWh
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer fabian, that's the route I'm currently using, but that's really quite cumbersome, and it does not work when the value isn't explicitly printed like this, as in e.g. `matplotlib` or `pandas.DataFrame`.   

The `UnitRegistry` initialisation function already has a `preprocessors` parameter; adding a `postprocessors` parameter would be a good general way of addressing the issue, AFAICS.

Comment: I realize that what you would need is something in the spirit of a `.to_defined_units()` function that does take all defined units into account analog to how `.to_base_units()` operates. I made some experiments and extended `.to_reduced_units()` to accept the priority list which in combination with setting `ureg.auto_reduce_dimensions = True` does the trick. It's a first shot, but it works in the case the unit can be reduced to a priority unit. See [here](https://github.com/fabianegli/pint/tree/reduce-to-prioritized-units). It still needs a way to set the priorities `ureg`-wide.

Comment: I added some example usage code to the [commit](https://github.com/fabianegli/pint/commit/d93c2e0fef148d2dbe2f84d987577583af5249a8). It would be great to get your take on that.

Comment: And here it is with registry wide defaults: https://github.com/fabianegli/pint/commit/9d7f5475aa0355c59539ae581db5eee63fc50200

Comment: Hey, that's great, many thanks! I did have some comments/suggestions, which I've added to the commit. It's gotten very long, sorry about that. I hope they are useful.